# How to get crisp image for search result suggestion in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm using a 40 x 40 sized image as a search result suggestion image in Windows 8 search. Only advice about the image format I can find is to have correct size for it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700542.aspx: "Windows will scale or crop smaller or larger images").

However, the correctly sized image blurs annoyingly. The same thing happens whether I use jpg or png. Original image looks fine, but the result suggestion in the search charm is very ugly, being still of same size! Is Windows converting the image somehow, and how could I get the image to stay crisp?

I haven't noticed blurring with photo-like images, but this image contains clear lines and areas which are vulnerable to any scaling etc.

**Update Sep 24:**

Here is the test image I used when trying to figure out the problem. I also created different scale versions, but in my case the 100% version was used (that's why the "100" marking) - as I supposed because the resulting image really is 40x40. As you can see, the resulting image (right) is of same size as original (left), but blurry.

[image: Original test image] 
[image: Blurry image in Windows 8 search]

Comment: Have you tried other sizes? Like 32 x 32 or 48 x 48? Sometimes the docs / samples may be out of date.

Comment: It doesn't help, and I can't see how this even could. The resulting image in the search charm really is 40x40 - it just isn't the same crisp image anymore.

Comment: I think that it might not be a "bug", but a "feature". Windows 8 with all his user experience think and optimalization stuff, could lead to such memory cut, since user can't see well details on 40x40 image anyway

Comment: I think your question duplicates mine asked 2 months ago. Never got any answer on that one. Often I find myself the solution if nobody replies but not this time...  If you (somebody) figure(s) out, please let me know there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589999/quality-of-the-search-result-images-in-metro-search-charm

Comment: @Skiba, I don't see how Windows could spare any significant amount of memory on such small image. And image quality is a big theme in Windows 8 - you can for example provide different scale versions of images, to make sure they look good in any resolution.

Comment: @JanZeman, sorry that I missed your existing question! Hopefully we get answer in either place.

Comment: No problem on my side at all. My temporary 'solution' was to use simpler images than originally intended. They get partly damaged too but the result is somehow acceptable. I wonder if somebody ever appears with the magical answer ;)

Comment: Riikka, out of curiosity... which graphical program do you use to export your pictures?

Comment: @JanZeman, do you mean creating the original images or saving the result image shown by Windows search charm? Original images were given to me by the designers (not included here), and the test images I made with Paint.net. Resulting image from search charm I captured with normal Print screen command, and pasted to Paint.net (and cropped there).

Comment: @RiikkaHeikniemi I meant creating of original images. I asked because I observed some 'strange' behavior in images I exported from GIMP (my graphical editor). So I was wondering whether the old problem described here could not be somehow related to the original graphical program and quality of images it produces. In my yesterday case (nothing to do with Win8 search) some of my images sized 32x32 and shown in 32x32 button were scaled incorrectly and screwed. After I reexported them to PNG with "Do not save resolution" option I got crisp images. I doubt this is a hint but maybe...

Comment: @JanZeman, thanks for idea. I tried exporting the test image from Gimp without the Save Resolution checkbox, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not happen that often but it seems the right solution in this case was simply to wait ;)  I haven't done anything new regarding result suggestion images in my solution and today I realized that the images became crisp. Probably fixed by any of the windows updates.

[image]

Comment: Now I can confirm 100% it was fixed by the Windows Update, as I ran the same program on an another computer - before and after update applied. After the update the quality of images increased drastically.

Comment: So it really was a bug in Windows, I kind of thought it must be. Cool that it works eventually! And thanks for figuring this out :)

Answer (score 1):

[Took a stab at answering what seems the related question mentioned in the comments, so I'm posting here as well.]

It sounds like this could be related to automatic scaling of the images.  Windows will automatically scale up/down based on pixel density, and you can help things scale well by either using vector-based images or, for bitmap images, supplying scale-specific versions.

For example, to scale an image referenced in markup as "AppLogo.jpg", you'd include these images:

- AppLogo.scale-100.jpg
- AppLogo.scale-140.jpg
- AppLogo.scale-180.jpg

You can also use folders, e.g. "\scale-140\AppLogo.jpg".

For search result images, the 100% image is the 40x40 pixel version, 140 is 56x56, and 180 is 72x72.  Just reference the image as "AppLogo.jpg" and the appropriate version will be used automatically.  (You can also detect scale with `DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale` and manually choose an image.)

Here's a couple of articles with more examples/details:

- ["Guidelines for scaling to pixel density"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx)
- ["Quickstart: Using file or image resources"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465262.aspx)

There's also some scaling discussion in the forums (general, not specific to search) [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/9458fec7-3426-433d-b633-12c6b8ded823) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/610718b0-69e8-42d2-a1fe-3c5be5b6515f).

Comment: I can't see how this would explain it, or help me get crisp search suggestion images. As I explained in the original post, I have (screencaptured and) measured the resulting image to be exactly the same 40 x 40 pixels as the original image, it just is blurred. I actually did try providing different scale versions for the image before posting the original question, but Windows uses the 100% scale version and still messes up the image.